# error handling when consume as a batch in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i have a kafka consumer written in java spring boot (spirng kafka). My consumer is like below.

```
@RetryableTopic(
          attempts = "4",
          backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2.0),
          autoCreateTopics = "false",
          topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE,
          include = {ResourceAccessException.class, MyCustomRetryableException.class})
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId = "myGroup", autoStartup = "true", concurrency = "3")
  public void consume(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                      @Header("custom_header_1") String customHeader1,
                      @Header("custom_header_2") String customHeader2,
                      @Header("custom_header_3") String customHeader3,
                      @Header(required = false, name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key,
                      @Payload(required = false) String message) {

    log.info("-------------------------");
    log.info(key);
    log.info(message);
    log.info("-------------------------");

  }
```

I have used `@RetryableTopic` annotation to handle errors. I have written a custom exception class and whatever method that throw my custom exception class (`MyCustomRetryableException.class`), it will retry according to the backoff with number of attempts defined in the retryable annotation. So in here i dont have to do anything. Kafka will simple publish failing messages to the correct dlt topic. All i have to do is create dlt related topic since i have used `autoCreateTopics = "false"`.

Now i'm trying to consume messages in batch wise. I changed my kafka config like below in order to consume in batch wise.

```
@Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
 
    // default configs like bootstrap servers, key and value deserializers are here

    config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "5");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
  }


  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.DEBUG);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    return factory;
  }
```

Now that i have added batch listeners, `@RetryableTopic` is not supported with it. So how can i achieve the publishing failed messages to DLT task which was previously handled by `@RetryableTopic` ?

If anyone can answer with an example it would be great. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh).

Use a `DefaultErrorHandler` with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.

Non blocking retries are not supported; the retries will use the configured `BackOff`.

Throw a `BatchListenerFailedException` to indicate which record in the batch failed and just that one will be sent to the DLT.

With any other exception, the whole batch will be retried (and sent to the DLT if retries are exhausted).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retrying-batch-eh

Comment: i added below config to the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`.

`factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);`

`factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1000L, 2L)));`


But it wont send the failed message to the defauls DLT topic (<originalTopic>.DLT). Is there anything that i'm missing

Comment: You need to add a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` to the error handler (`recoverer` constructor argument). The DLT is not created for you, you need to add a `NewTopic` bean for that. The default recoverer just logs the failed record. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters